# Add JavaScript file to all sites I browse

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extension development, I need to make something sample with extension.
I Need to add JavaScript file to all sites I browse when the extension enabled, this is the code i want to add to all pages

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="web-retina-emulator.js"></script>
```

This file make pages look like when the website on retina display.
Is there easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this basic structure to add JavaScript file to all sites when the extension enabled.

## Method 1

If `web-retina-emulator.js` is an individual file which do not use global variables or functions of pages where it is injected it is suggested to use this method

### Advantage:

It has access to certain sections of chrome API*

### Draw Back

It can not use javascript variables and functions of pages where it is  injected.

### Demonstration

#### manifest.json

```
{
"name":"Custom Script",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165629/add-javascript-file-to-all-sites-i-browse",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "js":["web-retina-emulator.js"],
}
]
}
```

## Method 2

If `web-retina-emulator.js` need some javascript methods or variables of pages, use this approach

### Advantage:

It has access to javascript variables and methods of pages

### Draw Back

It can not use chrome API*.

### Demonstration

#### manifest.json

```
{
"name":"Custom Script",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165629/add-javascript-file-to-all-sites-i-browse",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"content_scripts":[{
    "matches":["<all_urls>"],
    "js":["myscript.js"],
}
]
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); // Create a Script Tag
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("web-retina-emulator.js"); //Fetch the content script
script.onload = function () {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this); //Remove script after script executed
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script); //ADD script tag 
                                                       //to head or Html element
```

## Method 3

Inserting code into a page programmatically is useful when your JavaScript or CSS code shouldn't be injected into every single page that matches the pattern — for example, if you want a script to run only when the user clicks a browser action's icon.

### Demonstration

#### background.html

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
{file:"web-retina-emulator.js"});
```

#### manifest.json

Ensure permissions are set in manifest file

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```

## References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Execute Script API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en). It's the chrome equivalent to greasemonkey.

Comment: Nice, i'm trying to get any userscripts code to help me out, i searched a lot and got nothing